# React Router alias naming route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have route in version `"react-router-dom": "^6.7.0"`

```
<Route path="/categories" element={<Categories />} />
```

I am navigating to this `"/categories"` route on multiple pages with

```
onClick={() => {
  return navigate("/categories");
}}
```

Now my concern is that if my route path `<Route path="/categories"` changes in future to `<Route path="/categories-abcde"` then I will have to change everywhere in program `navigate("/categories")` to `navigate("/categories-abcde")`.

Is there any name aliasing like `<Route path="/categories" element={<Categories />} alias='somename' />` that I can use everywhere in `navigate("/somename")`. So that if route path `<Route path="/categories"` changed then I do not have to change in `navigate("/somename")` everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

A feature like this doesn't exist in `react-router` but doing a global search and replace is a very trivial action. Search and replace can be prone to typos though, either there's a typo on a specific target path so it doesn't get replaced, or the person making the change typo replaces *all* the target paths.

To resolve this issue the solution is also trivial, store all the route paths in a configuration object.

Example routes.types.js:

```
export const ROUTES = {
  ...
  CATEGORIES: "/categories",
  ...
  HOME: "/",
  ...
};
```

Usage:

```
<Route path={ROUTES.CATEGORIES} element={<Categories />} />
```

```
onClick={() => {
  navigate(ROUTES.CATEGORIES);
}}
```

Now when the route path needs to be updated it is updated in one location where it's declared and all instances of its usage automatically read the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

No, React Router doesn't have an `alias` like property.

---

There are multiple ways to tackle this, eg:

##### Add a single point where the name is returned

```
# Define
export const getCategoriesNavigator = () => navigate("/categories");

# Use 
onClick={getCategoriesNavigator}
```

Should your route change, you only have to change a single point

##### Match them all!

You could extend your route to `path="/categories*"` (note the `*`)

This way stuff like your example, `/categories-abcde` will still be captured by that route, so no need to change any `navigate()`